# how to model this in object oriented way

Tags: object, oop

I have following Entities in my system

```
public class Student
    {
        public Guid StudentId { set; get; }
        public string StudentName { set; get; }
        public virtual Course[] Courses { set; get; }
    }

 public class Teacher
    {
        public Guid TeacherId { get; set; }
        public string TeacherName { get; set; }
        public virtual Course[] Courses { get; set; }
    }


public class Course
    {
        public Guid CourseId { set; get; }
        public string CourseName { set; get; }
        public Student[] Students { set; get; }
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; } 
        public Test[] Tests{ get; set;}
    }


public class Test
    {
        public Guid TestId { get; set; }
        public String TestName { get; set; }
        public int TotalMarks { get; set; }
        public int PassingMarks { get; set; }
    }
```

Each student can subscribe to many courses and each course can have many students

Each teacher can teach many courses and each course can have one teacher

Each course can have many Tests

For example, there is a course called "Maths" and this lasts for 6 months and during these six months several tests are conducted

What will b the correct data structure if i want to store following data "For student S1 marks for the test t1" "For student s1 marks for the test t2"

I know i can have a many to many relationship between Tests and Students,
but there is already a many to many relationship between students and course and course contains Test.

Comment: Is this a homework problem btw?  If so, should get the homework tag.

Comment: no, Its not a homework problem :) Its my Pet Project though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider having a class, say "Marks", that contains the relationship Student -> Mark and Mark -> Test.

In general, when you're doing an object-oriented design, at this domain level your classes and relationships are nouns and verbs in your use-case or description.  In this case, you know your Student has Marks; these are specific to the student.  The Student doesn't have Tests, because those aren't created or controlled by the student.

**Update**

Yes, the idea is that you'd have a class Marks, with a relationship in Student to their Marks; the Marks would have a relationship to its Test.  In other words, "a Student has Marks for a Test" -- these things are actually naturally in the language of the problem once you learn to look at it right.

So that would be something like

```
class Student { // lots of other fields
    marks : set of Marks  // any convenient structure
                          // logically a Set because you wouldn't have the
                          // same marks assigned to a student twice
}

class Marks {  // A Mark is the Student's score for a test
    Score s;
    Test t;
    Student stud; // see below
}

class Test { // other information needed here too
    marks : set of Marks
}
```

Now, you have a structure of classes that lets you ask "What are the students marks on their tests?", and from that you can ask "what were those tests?"  Going the other way, you can ask "What marks were given for these tests?" and "Who were those students?" which is why Marks needs a back-relation to Student.

Two things to note:

(1) this is a very common pattern in an OO analysis -- a many-many relationship turns into a "helper class" that represents it.

(2) if you are then going to put this in a database, there is a second issue: the natural thing to do is to make each class a separate table; this scheme works fine if you can look up items in a table at nearly zero cost (say in access time.)  In a real database, you're having to hit the disk multiple times for this access, and it gets slow.  This is what's called the "object relational impedance mismatch problem".  There are a number of solutions for it that involve either denormalizing the database, creating extra indices or views to pre-compute the relationships, or modifying your object model.

Comment: what do you mean by this "contains the relationship Student -> Mark and Mark -> Test."

Comment: Do you mean to say that i will have a class called Marks which will contain two properties Student and Test

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.. i again revisited same kind of situation and your answer helped a lot